# Variable not visible in basic Java class

Tags: java

I'm trying to build an ArrayList of `Earthquake` objects but Java is complaining about not being visible.

My Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays.*;

public class ObservatoryTest {
    private ArrayList <Earthquakes> listOfEarthquakes; //This list is not visible
    Earthquakes Quake1 = new Earthquakes(4.5,"cheese",1995);
    Earthquakes Quake2 = new Earthquakes(6.5,"fish",1945);
    Earthquakes Quake3 = new Earthquakes(10.5,"Chorizo",2015);

    public void buildList(Earthquakes... args){
        for(Earthquakes myEarthquake : args){
            listOfEarthquakes.add(myEarthquake);
        }

    }
}
```

My aim is to build a list of Earthquake objects. Could somebody tell me why and how to fix my code? Thanks

--------------edit--------------------

The error message is `the type ArrayList is not visible` however changing visibility modifier to public doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Complaining how, where? What's the exact compilation error? What do you think _not being visible_ means given that the field is `private`?

Comment: add the import java.util.ArrayList; and see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing the below import statement

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class ObservatoryTest {

 private ArrayList <Earthquakes> listOfEarthquakes; //This list is not visible
    Earthquakes Quake1 = new Earthquakes(4.5,"cheese",1995);
    Earthquakes Quake2 = new Earthquakes(6.5,"fish",1945);
    Earthquakes Quake3 = new Earthquakes(10.5,"Chorizo",2015);

    public void buildList(Earthquakes... args){
        for(Earthquakes myEarthquake : args){
            listOfEarthquakes.add(myEarthquake);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 7):

For some reason, you've used a [type-import-on-demand declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.2) for nested member of `Arrays`

```
import java.util.Arrays.*;
```

In its current implementation, `Arrays` declares a `private` nested type named `ArrayList`. That's not visible to your code since it's `private`.

You meant to import `java.util.ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the import statement for `ArrayList`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

To solve such problems call the "Organize imports" from you SDE. e.g in Eclipse: Ctrl-Shift-O

Comment: how you know is not in the package?

Answer (score -1):

You need to initialize the list before adding the elements to it !

```
listOfEarthquakes = new ArrayList<Earthquakes>();
listOfEarthquakes.add(myEarthquake);
```

Comment: By the way - when I had posted my answer, the "---edit---" part was not there - so it was not clear what the exact error was ! and anyways this list was not initialized anyways - at least in the posted code. So I'm a little surprised by the downvote !

Comment: I had not downvoted, However, if finally, even after an edit of the original question, the answer is wrong. It is ok that finally it is downvoted, because it is a wrong answer. You can remove the answer, then your  reputation points, you lost, will be returned to you